# What percentage of NAACP in the 1910s was Jewish?

Tags: civil-rights

> However, by the mid-1910s, the NAACP had several prominent Jewish members. Brothers Joel and Arthur Spingarn served as board chairman and chief legal counsel, respectively. Herbert Lehman served on the executive committee. Lillian Wald and Walter Sachs served on the board. Jacob Schiffand Paul Warburg were financiers for the organization. By 1920, Herbert Seligmann was director of public relations and Martha Greuning served as his assistant. Other prominent Jewish figures involved in the NAACP founding were Jacob Billikopf, Julius Rosenwald, Rabbi Emil G. Hirsch and Rabbi Stephen Wise. No wonder Marcus Garvey stormed out of the NAACP headquarters in 1917 complaining that it was a White organization.

https://fanghornforest.wordpress.com/2015/11/18/national-association-for-the-advancement-of-kosher-people/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not about conspiracy theories or pseudo-science http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . Try asking on Skeptics.SE instead.

Answer (score 2):

The NAACP was founded around 1910, not the "mid 1910s" by [Mary White Ovington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_White_Ovington), a gentile. In 1914, she wrote a short pamphlet entitled "How the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People Began". According to this account nearly all the founding members were gentiles, although an important figure at the beginning was [Henry Moscowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Moskowitz_%28civil_rights_leader%29), a close of Ovington's. Another important figure was [William English Walling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_English_Walling), who came from a prominent Southern family, but was influenced by his wife, [Anna Strunsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Strunsky), a Russian Jew highly involved in various social causes. The original officers of the organization were:

[Moorfield Storey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moorfield_Storey)
William English Walling
John E. Milholland
[Oswald Garrison Villard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oswald_Garrison_Villard)
Frances Blascoer
[William Edward Burghardt Du Bois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._E._B._Du_Bois)

Among these only Blascoer was Jewish. In general, the main body of the organization was composed of wealthy Protestant abolitionists like Storey, Milholland and Villard and there were many Christian clergy. Jewish members, like Walling's wife, were certainly present, but they were a minority, perhaps making up 10% - 15% at most.

Comment: @JacobBlaustein If this answer seems correct and complete to you, please accept it.